# Bukkit Custom death system

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

i'm making a bedwars plugin for a minecraft server, i'm actually at the custom death system, i have a code that works :

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        e.getEntity().spigot().respawn();
        String[] pos = Main.death_coords.split("\\*");
        World w = e.getEntity().getWorld();
        Location loc = new Location(w, Double.parseDouble(pos[0]), Double.parseDouble(pos[1]), Double.parseDouble(pos[2]));
        e.getEntity().teleport(loc);
        e.getEntity().setGameMode(GameMode.SPECTATOR);

        task = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, () -> {
            int count = 5;
            if(count == 0) {
                task.cancel();
                sendtitle("SusyBaka", e.getEntity());
                e.getEntity().setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
            } else {
                count--;
                sendtitle(Integer.toString(count), e.getEntity());
            }
        }, 20, 20);
    }
```

but when i get killed, i stucks, beaucause count is a new variable every sec and it's stucks a 5, i tried to make count a public int variable but it's just work for 1 death, else is instant respawn.
How to make that works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `count` variable outside the method (i.e. public) is a good idea. Actually, you are doing this:

1. count = 5. count -1 -> 4.
2. count = 5. count -1 -> 4.
3. count = 5. count -1 -> 4.
4. etc...

You have to set the counter as public, but also link it to the user. You can do it with a Map.

There is also another solution, which is better: don't use lambda in this case, and use this instead :

```java
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
   // here your code

   task = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, new Runnable() {
        // complete runnable instance instead of implicit one
        private int count = 5; // counter define only for this runnable instance

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == 0) {
                task.cancel();
                // finished
            } else {
                count--; // here it will remove 1 but keep it for next iteration
                sendtitle(Integer.toString(count), e.getEntity());
            }
        }
    }, 20, 20);
}
```